# Theory for pre-paid debit card: card-to-card transfer

Tags: algorithm-design, reference-request

In Sweden in the late 90's they deployed a electronic prepaid cash system system, and if I remember correctly you could transfer money between cards without online access. Wikipedia states that the dis-continued systems TransCash, 247card and iKobo had the same function.

On usage would be

1. You load up your card at a ATM, paying with your normal bank card (online connection)
2. You meet your friend and the cards communicate somehow at an offline terminal
3. Your friend pay with the money at an offline point-of-sales terminal

This got me wondering on what crypto theories that could solve this kind of problem.

**EDIT:** Found this link about "[continued fractions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.228.959)"  and will try to get through the math...

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Ive come so far that the card needs a private key or challenge-response-function, both relying on that you cant clone the card. If the card can be physically cloned, there exists no safe scheme

Comment: That's one kind of approach.  The other kind is to use a coin-based scheme for e-cash, e.g., Chaum-style e-cash (based upon blind signatures).

Answer (score 2):

There are many techniques: e-cash (coin-based schemes) can achieve this; also systems that use tamper-resistant smartcards (e.g., Mondex, in the US).  If you trust the tamper-resistance of the card, then it's easy to devise a protocol for stored-value cards that can provide this functionality.